# Photovoltaics or photovoltaic systems

Tags: terminology

I have the following sentence and I'd like to hear your opionon on that:

"Electrictiy generated from **photovoltaics**..."

Is it correct to use the term "photovoltaics" or do I have to use "photovoltaic systems"?

I'd appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.

Comment: Electricity generated from photovoltaic cells. 'Photovoltaics' is a branch of technology, not an electricity generation system.

Comment: Thanks Weather for your comment. But I want to put emphasis of the PV rooftop system itself not on the cells.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Weather for your answer. Okay, as I do not want to choose cells I will use 'photovoltatic systems'

Comment: Depends on your audience, and the stuffiness of the publication.

Comment: @HotLicks It would also depend on the extent to which the term had been introduced earlier in the article. If there had been a longish discussion of the systems earlier then using "photovoltaics" as a sort of shorthand would be fine.

Comment: @BoldBen - Many people would understand "photovoltaics" without need for an introduction.  I've certainly seen it used dozens of times.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree, I'm happy with it myself. I was thinking in terms of your stuffier publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct because the meaning is clear, unambiguous, and concise.

There are already long-established precedents in scientific usage: mechanics, electrostatics, hydraulics, kinetics ... a long list of nouns derived from adjectives, in each case encompassing a large body of knowledge or practice within one word. It is neither necessary nor helpful to replace such terms by noun phrases such as “mechanical systems” or “photovoltaic cells” unless the further discussion of the matter justifies it.

Comment: Thanks Anton for your answer.